# itext library Document.add(Element element) method returns true and does not throw any exception when the disk gets full while writing PDF files

Tags: java, itext

I am using itext java library to generate PDF files to a windows hard disk. 
The method I am using is

> com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Element element)

This method is called by multiple threads (configurable).
Let me explain what is happening with some example numbers below:
For example, I have to write 10 pdf files each with 100KB size. The total size required is 1000KB. The space available in the hard disk is 500KB.
There are three things happening:

1. When the code starts executing it initially creates some file with 100KB. Let us say 2 files created and add() method returns true which indicates the file is successfully created (this is expected behavior)
2. Then it creates some incomplete files with 50KB or 60KB or 40KB (Some number less than actual size) and throws IOException. In this case I mark the document "incomplete" and later when the disk space is available I rewrite the file. That time older files gets overwritten by new file and the new file is perfect.
3. Now, let us say 6 files are written and only 4 files are left(it could be 2 or 3 also). In this case incomplete files with 2KB or 0KB or 4KB are getting created and the add() method DOES NOT THROW ANY EXCEPTION AND RETURNS "TRUE" (which means the file successfully written).  These files become corrupt. I cannot rewrite when disk space is available because I am told that it is successfully written.

So the issue is with third scenario. The method behaves buggy towards the end. In 2nd scenario it throws exception where as it does do so in third scenario.
My code writes thousands of files and in production huge number of threads are configured for multiple servers.

And this code works perfectly when ample disk space is available and issue is when disk space gets exhausted when the files are being written.

The itext library version I am using is 5.0.6.
Any help please?

Comment: Adding an element to a document does not immediately trigger a disc write. Depending on the document structure nearly everything may be written when closing the document. Doo you get some error during `close`?

Comment: I don't know whether any exception is thrown during close. My point is why add method returns true when the disk write is not done yet?

Comment: *why add method returns true when the disk write is not done yet?* - Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP clarified in a comment:

> My point is why add method returns true when the disk write is not done yet?

The method comment says:

```
/**
 * Adds an <CODE>Element</CODE> to the <CODE>Document</CODE>.
 *
 * @param element
 *            the <CODE>Element</CODE> to add
 * @return <CODE>true</CODE> if the element was added, <CODE>false
 *         </CODE> if not
 * @throws DocumentException
 *             when a document isn't open yet, or has been closed
 */
```

So according to the documentation a `true` merely means that the element was added to this `Document` instance itself, not some file on disc.

As you surely know an iText `Document` merely is a document abstraction to which registered `DocListener` instances listen, and if at least one of those listeners returns `true` for an `add`, the `Document.add` returns true.

A `PdfWriter.getInstance` call adds a new `PdfDocument` instance as `Document` listener, and `PdfDocument.add` returns `true` as long as the associated writer neither is `null` nor paused and the element to add is of a known type and no exception is thrown here. So most likely it returns `true` all the time in your program.

By the way:

> The itext library version I am using is 5.0.6

That version is ancient, so unless you have a very special support contract, you likely won't get a binary compatible library version behaving as you expect.

Comment: This answer is correct and should be accepted. iText keeps the element that was added to the `Document` in memory until there is sufficient content for a full page. Once the page is full, content is flushed to the `OutputStream`. The `OutputStream` isn't necessarily a `FileOutputStream`. It would not be a good idea to introduce concepts such as disk space as that would assume that you're always writing to a file (which is most certainly not the case in most iText applications, especially not in a web context).

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Like you rightly mentioned when disk space is not available document.close() throws IOException and gives a message that disk space not available. So, I am handling the exception here. That solves my problem. However, in my original question why add() method throws exception in case 2 and why it does not throw in case 3 is still a mystery to me :-). Thanks again guys!!

Comment: *However, in my original question why add() method throws exception in case 2 and why it does not throw in case 3 is still a mystery to me* - as @Bruno said, content is written when a page is full. Probably in case 2 a page was flushed during adding (without enough disc space) and in case 3 the disc space was depleted only in the final flush in `close`.